# delete item the order changes php

Tags: php

I have a page that has a column "order". When I add a new item the order should be 1 + max of the item. But if I delete an item between these values like i have 8 9 10 , if I delete item with 9 the new item will have 11 value and I will have 8 10 11.But I want 8 9 10. How can I do this in php? should I create a function? It works to add a new item with the max+1, but if I delete is not good.
My code:

```
$queryMaxOrd = mysql_query("select max(ord) from article where user_id=" .$_SESSION['userId']);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($queryMaxOrd);
$valueMaxOrd = $row[0] + 1;
$_SESSION['a'] = $valueMaxOrd;
```

and the insert query....

Any ideas?

Comment: From your question and your query i think that you adding records to your table. When you are selecting the MAX value always you will get the maximum value that is connecting with this user. Best think to do is use update

Comment: ok, but I want even when I insert something to have the value max + 1

Comment: try to use sum in place of max

Answer (score 0):

First thing to consider is removing mysql_* and start using mysqli_* or pdo. Your code is vulnerable to sql injections.

With your code structure you have you adding each order as a new record to your table, so when you have 5 orders with one users your table will look like this.

```
user: Adiiia | order: 5
user: Adiiia | order: 3
user: Adiiia | order: 7
user: Adiiia | order: 2
user: Adiiia | order: 9
```

when you query the database you are saying to mysql: get me the maximum number of the record i have with `user: Adiiia`. The result should be `9`

If you want to count the sum of the records you should use `sum`

```
select sum(ord) from article where user_id='".$_SESSION['userId']."'
```

The result should be `26`

The best thing you can do is by creating a new table `orders_sum`

The structure should like like this.

```
Total_orders | User
```

when a user have a new order you can update the table by adding one or else if have a order removed then removing minus one order.

Something like this.

```
Total_orders | User
     5       | Adiiia
```

When you want to update:

```
select Total_orders from orders_sum where User='Adiiia'
```

Find how many orders the user have by fetching the table.

```
$orders = $row['Total_orders'];
$plus_orders = $row['Total_orders'] + 1;

update orders_sum set Total_orders='".$plus_orders."' where user='Adiiia'
```

When you want to delete:

```
select Total_orders from orders_sum where User='Adiiia'
```

Find how many orders the user have by fetching the table.

```
$orders = $row['Total_orders'];
$minus_orders = $row['Total_orders'] - 1;

update orders_sum set Total_orders='".$minus_orders."' where user='Adiiia'
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say article table having primary key article_id then after delete any article for user_id. Fetch all the article_id for the user_id. Then update the order for all the article_id for that user.

```
$queryArticle = mysql_query("select article_id from article where user_id=" .$_SESSION['userId']." order by article_id asc");
$allArticle = [];
while($rowArticle = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryArticle)){
  $allArticle[] = $rowArticle['article_id'];
}

$query = "UPDATE article SET ord = (CASE order ";
foreach($allArticle as $order => $article_id) {
  $query .= " WHEN {$article_id} THEN {$order}";
}
$query .= " END CASE) WHERE article_id IN (" . implode(",", $allArticle) . ")";
```